# Unable to import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController; Can't use @Restcontroller

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-restcontroller

**Here is my code`**

```
package com.example.demo3;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController; 

`@RestController`

public class BooksC {
 //Code
}
```

**Here is my pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo3</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And I have already tried with other RELEASE and Versions and Dependencies
but the problem remains the same
I just tried to make you show the problem with the demo class *BooksC*

**Here I had used spring initializer**
[image: Here I had used spring initializer]

With Eclipse Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add REST dependency

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the dependency Spring-web dependency to your pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then it should work fine

Comment: Working fine now thanxx